# Limit of a sequence of sets of partial sums.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S = \{(\alpha_k) : \alpha_k = 0 \vee \alpha_k = 2\}$ (the set of all sequences whose entries are either $0$ or $2$). Let $\lambda_{0} = \{0\}$, and

$$\lambda_{n+1} = \frac{\lambda_{n}}{3} \cup \big( \frac{\lambda_{n}}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \big)$$

for all $n \geq 0$. I can show by induction that

$$\lambda_{N} = \Bigg\{\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\alpha_{n}}{3^{n}} : (\alpha_k) \in S\Bigg\}.$$

Can I say, then, that

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n = \Bigg\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_{n}}{3^{n}} : (\alpha_k) \in S\Bigg\}?$$

Comment: A side note: $S=\{0,2\}^{\Bbb N}$. Also, what does a set divided by a number means and a set added to a number mean? regarding to the question itself, try to use the definition of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ to see whether or not it is true

Comment: Hi, thank you! In regards to the notation, I mean that if $A = \{x,y,z\}$ then $n + A = \{n+x, n+y, n+z\}$ and $A/n = \{x/n , y/n, z/n\}$. I tried using the definition of limit of a sequence of sets, but I don't know if the union on the left can even include an infinite series, or if it only contains partial sums. It is all very confusing to me. Update: Actually, the more I think about it, I could perhaps show that the union on the left is perfect and so is equal to the set of its limit points, which is probably the set on the right.

Comment: Your definition for the set on the right-hand side is ambiguous since conditions for $n$ in RHS is not mentioned. For example, you could take $a_k=2$ for all $k$ which will make $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{3^n} \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that. The index is supposed to range over all n. I have fixed it.

Comment: Let $a_n=2$ when $n$ is odd and let  $a_n=0$ when $n$ is even .In base $3$ we have $3/4=0.\overline {20}=$ $=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n3^{-n}\not \in$ $ \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can only claim that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n \subset \Big\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\alpha_{n}}{3^{n}} : (\alpha_k) \in S\Big\}$.

Note that each element of the left-hand side $\lambda_n$ can be uniquely written as a sum of *finite* number of terms $\frac{a_n}{3^n}$ while on the right-hand side, there are elements that don't satisfy this condition.

Comment: Thank you! This was causing me a lot of trouble.